# login page authentication ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

Here i want to integrate API for my login page.

Frontend code on ReactJS:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import SignUp from './signup';


const Login = () =>  {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  
  
    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        console.log("success0");
      const { data } = await Axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/login/"+email
      );
 
      let parseData = JSON.parse(data.response);
  
      setProducts(parseData);

     if(products.password==password){
     //render to sign up page
     }

    };


    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
          
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="d-grid">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )

}

export default Login;
```

[image: This is my login page i am asking email and password from user]

[image: Here is the response from the API]

here i taking email and password from the user and through email if i am searching data of the user then i am matching the password. If the password get matched i need to render it to signup page.

Comment: have you heard of react-router https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6?

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you use react-router-dom version ^6.2.2

in your handleSubmit add this code and import react-router-dom

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();

 if(products.password==password){
     navigate(`/anyroute`)
     }
```

Comment: i did this but it is redirecting to the same page

Comment: Please check this codesandbox link I have created sample demo for you https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leftpad-70d1z9?file=/src/App.js